# Matplotlib: change position of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I did the following plot with the figure size (which should not be changed):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the x-label is not fully visible. My question: Is it possible, to move the whole grafic to the top (because there would be enough space)?

The code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
plt.plot(time_load,load, linewidth=1.5)
plt.grid(True)
plt.tick_params(labelsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Time [hours]',fontsize=16)
plt.xlim([0,24])
plt.xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20,24])
plt.legend(loc="upper left",fontsize = 'large')
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How do you imagine us helping you without seeing the code that produced this figure?

Comment: Sorry! I added the code

Answer (score 11):

You can also try

```
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.19)
```

If 0.19 adds too much or too little space to see the x-label better, then try adjusting little by little up or down.

Answer (score 9):

A very simple approach is to use

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

See: http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the axes() command that allows you to specify the location as axes. You can also use the xlim() command and ylim() command. In your case, you can use the latter. So just as an example, the xlim method can be used like this:

```
plt.xlim(X.min()*1.1, X.max()*1.1)
plt.ylim(C.min()*1.1, C.max()*1.1)
```

This will make some space for the data points to be seen clearly. Hope that helps.
**Just seen the code so you're using xlim method. You want to create the subplot somewhere else, for that you can use the axis() method.**

```
plt.axes([0.3, 0.3, .5, .5])
```

You can adjust plot accordingly. This one will create a subplot in the upper right corner of the figure.

Comment: Please add the meaning of the 4 values in the `axes()` rect definition

Comment: Thank you very much! I just found the comand "plt.tight_layout()" --> what do you think about that?

Comment: @Matias It seems to be exactly what you need. Why don't you self-answer your question?